# Multiple data bindings in Ampersand JS

Tags: javascript, ampersand.js

I have a model:

```
var Person = AmpersandState.extend({
    props: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            default: ''
        }
    },
    session: {
        isSitting: {
            type: 'boolean',
            default: false
        }
    },
    toggleState: function () {
        this.toggle('isSitting');
    }
});
```

a view:

```
var PersonView = AmpersandView.extend({
    template: Templates.person,
    events: {
        'change [type=checkbox]': 'handleCheckbox'
    },
    bindings: {
        'model.name': {
            type: 'text',
            hook: 'name'
        },
        'model.isSitting': [
            {
                type: 'toggle',
                hook: 'sitting'
            },
            {
                type: 'toggle',
                hook: 'standing'
            }
        ]
    },
    handleCheckbox: function () {
        this.model.toggleState();
    }
});
```

and a template:

```
<li>
    <div data-hook="name"></div>
    <span data-hook="sitting">is sitting</span>
    <span data-hook="standing">is standing</span>
    <input type="checkbox">
</li>
```

so when the checkbox is changed, it toggles `isSitting` property on the model and therefore the visibility of `span` with `data-hook="sitting"` is toggled accordingly. But what I want to do is toggle `data-hook="standing" span` as well, but toggle it so that it does the opposite.

So when `sitting` span is hidden, `standing` span should be shown. Is is possible to do this using multiple data bindings anyhow? Or do I have to explicitly define another property like `isStanding` on the model and in my `toggleState` method, toggle that property as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `yes` and `no` keys on the toggle binding:

```
// show/hide where true/false show different things

'model.isSitting': {
    type: 'toggle',
    yes: '[data-hook=sitting]',
    no: '[data-hook=standing]'
}
```

As seen on https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-dom-bindings#toggle